# After my dot why is it not capitalizing the word?

Tags: python-2.7, class, capitalization

```
class Capitalize:

    def __init__(self, capitalize):
        self.capitalize = capitalize.capitalize()
        #self.capitalize_dot =
        def cap():
            list =  self.capitalize.split('.')
            list[item[1].capitalize]


name = Capitalize('simon.hello')
print(name.capitalize)
>>>>Simon.hello
```

I want the hello to be also capitalized. I don't see what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `l = '.'.join([w.capitalize() for w in s.split('.')])`. Also don't name a variable `list` since it's a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the value that create in your function `cap()` and never call this !

I think is better create an array like in your function `cap()` but without use a function, then with this values use a `for` and capitalize each word and finally use `join` to set the `self.capitalize`

```
class Capitalize:
    def __init__(self, capitalize):
        # the array of words capitalized
        wordsCapitalize = []
        # the array of words that you send and convert to array using the '.'
        words = capitalize.split('.') 
        # Iterate over the array of words
        for word in words:
            # add new value to the array of words capitalized
            # word is capitalize with function capitalize()
            wordsCapitalize.append(word.capitalize())
        # set the value to self.capitalize using '.' like character to join the values of array with words capitalized
        self.capitalize = '.'.join(wordsCapitalize)

name = Capitalize('simon.hello')
print(name.capitalize)
```

Show me:

```
Simon.Hello
```

I write the most simple code for the begginers.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, could you please go into detail on what is happening here though?

Answer (score 0):

Please [read the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq):

> str.capitalize()
>
> Return a copy of the string with its **first** character capitalized and **the rest lowercased**.

Comment: How does this fix my issue?

Comment: @OkCoder It doesn't fix the issue, but it does answer your question "Why is it not capitalizing the word"